# Can you tell if a HOMO to LUMO transition is allowed just by picturing the MOs?

Tags: physical-chemistry, computational-chemistry, molecular-orbital-theory

Someone told me that they said the HOMO to LUMO transition is allowed in benzene and naphthalene just by looking at the MOs and without using the irreps for each orbital and the character tables?

How can you do this? I thought you need to use the character and product tables to determine whether a transition is allowed (non-zero transition dipole matrix) Is there a method in doing so involving the symmetry of the lobes of each orbital?

Comment: You will always have to look at the symmetry each of the MO's with the point group to determine its symmetry species. You also need to know the sym. species for the x,y,z transition moment vector, so five sym species in total.  Of course if one  is the ground state it is always totally symmetric so you know this just by looking and as its totally symmetric can be ignored.  (btw the lowest energy transition in benzene is forbidden so whoever told you this has not got it quite sorted yet)

Comment: @porphyrin so does the HOMO-LUMO transition in benzene give a zero transition dipole matrix element? If so, why?

Comment: In principle why not? Remember ultimately all symmetry arguments are are a more general version of "an even function times an odd function is an odd function, hence the integral over all space of the product is zero". Consider a simple case Hydrogen 1s to Hydrogen 2s - it's easy (at least to me) to see that the transition dipole matrix element for x, y, or z is zero by the odd/even argument - and if you can visualise more complicated cases I don't see why you couldn't see if in certain cases an integral is zero or not simply by "looking"

Comment: yes it is forbidden, which is why with complicated MO's we need to use symmetry, and yes the transition moment is zero. The weak uv spectrum observed is due to coupling with a nearby state of the correct symmetry to effectively 'borrow' some intensity. Called Herzberg-Teller coupling or intensity stealing. See J. Steinfeld 'Molecules & Radiation' for a clear discussion, p270-276.